# Unit Testing Ajax calls

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, mocha.js, sinon

I need some advice on unit testing. I am using mocha and sinon.

I have an httpService module that deals with all the ajax requests (written by me). The file being tested requires the httpService module.

I am unit testing a function that makes a call to a private function in the same file which in turn calls the httpService.get()

What is the best way to unit test this?

The options I have come up with:

1) I could use the sinon FakeXMLHttpRequest to fake the Ajax response. However because the ajax request is being made from the httpService module I am now testing the functionality of the httpService module. Is this not integration testing?

2) I could require the httpService module into my unit test file and stub the httpService.get() function. Is requiring a module into my unit test acceptable practice even if it is to just stub function?

Nothing else is exposed from the file being tested.

Any other options?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct in that your option 1 is going too far. Your unit tests should be limited to testing your current function.

Option 2 is getting there... I would require the httpService module, but then create a sinon spy to spy on the httpService.get function.

sinon.spy(object, "method")

That way you can simply check whether your method resulted in a call to the http service.

You should read the documentation on spies here...

[Sinon spies](http://sinonjs.org/releases/v4.0.0/spies/)

Comment: Thanks for your response, I really appreciate it!. Just another quick one. If the httpService.get returns some data that is used in the file under test, in this case it is setting up a view model object, should I be testing that the view model object has been updated after calling the function under test. In which case I guess I would need to use a stub? If I am using BDD do I need to test that the httpService.get() function has been called (using a spy) or am I just interested in the fact that the view model object has been updated. Sorry for all the questions!

Comment: Yes sinon.stubs look like the way to go in that situation. You can basically tell the stub what to return with the .returns prefix.